# Can not fetch Android SDK with Android Studio RC4 on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to start Android Studio RC4 on a freshly installed Ubuntu.
I'm under a proxy so I have set my proxy in Ubuntu System Settings.

Yet, I'm getting this when starting Android Studio:

```
[   6987]   WARN - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Connection failed. Please check your network connection and try again.
```

and the process seems to hang up at "Fetching Android SDK".

I've tried `export http_proxy=...` to no avail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create or modify file:
`~/.AndroidStudio/config/options/other.xml`
or
`~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/options/other.xml`
depending on Android Studio version.

Fill in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <component name="HttpConfigurable">
    <option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
    <option name="PROXY_HOST" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <option name="PROXY_PORT" value="3128" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Replace `127.0.0.1` and `3128` with you http proxy settings.

Comment: os osx, this configuration variable is at~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options/other.xml

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach to this problem. After editing the `other.xml` file there was no real results. My terminal still had `[   5154]   WARN - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Connection failed. Please check your network connection and try again.`

The next approach for me was locating the `idea.properties` file within `android-studio` > `bin` and adding

> disable.android.first.run=true

to the last line of the file. This will disable first run and the associated hang.

Then I went to the  android studio `File` > `Settings` > `HTTP Proxy` settings and made changes to the proxy settings. After which the line added earlier to the `idea.properties` file was deleted.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding my proxy settings into the following file '.AndroidStudio/config/options/other.xml'